# mvc3 render view from iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iframe

I have a controller which creates a url for an iFrame by calling a webservice. I need to create a view and a model and pass this url of the iFrame to the view. How do i do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Controller
ViewBag.IframeUrl = theIframeUrl;
View("ViewName");

//View
<iframe src="@ViewBag.IframeUrl"></iframe>
```

This is the simplest way. Depending on your problem you may want to use a model / viewmodel.